# Replace ice:selectInputDate with jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, icefaces, jsf-1.1

I have a JSF 1.1 with IceFaces 1.6.2 project, where in the form I use `<ice:selectInputDate />`, but that component uses server resources for rendering Date, I want to change it with JS implementation. How I can do it? I saw [that](http://jsfbrickyard.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-better-alternative-for-the-icefaces-inputselectinputdate-control/) tutorial, but I am a newbie, and I don't exactly know, what files to configure. My implemenation of form is:

```
<ice:selectInputDate    id="genDate"
    binding="#{frm_4_20Bean.genDateInput}"
    renderAsPopup="true" 
    highlightUnit="DAY_OF_WEEK" 
    highlightValue="1,7" 
    highlightClass="weekend"
    required="false"
    value="#{frm_4_20Bean.genDate}">
</ice:selectInputDate>
```

How I can replace it with jQuery UI Datepicker which is described in tutorial above?